# JavaScript Regex to remove versions from String

Tags: javascript, regex

In a browser user agent string, if i wanna remove only the version after the / and except for Mozilla what can i do?

Example:

FROM:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3 WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36
```

TO:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3 WOW64) AppleWebKit (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome Safari
```

It's possible using regex?

Comment: Yep. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript regex doesn't have negative lookbehind unfortunately.  You could use a custom replacer function to get what you want.

Something like the following may work for you.

```
var userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3 WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36';
var reg = /(?:mozilla)?(\/(?:\d+\.*)+)/gi;
userAgent.replace(reg, function(match) { return (match.toLowerCase().indexOf('mozilla') !== -1) ? match : ''; });
```